# Assigning tasks to existing threads once they are free java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a large set of words and I need to execute a task on each individual word. I want to make it multithreaded in order to increase the speed. Currently, I am just using a foreach loop to iterate through each item in the list. What I want to do is have 8 threads that check the word I give them and then write a result to a file.

Currently, this is the code I am using:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("http.agent", "Chrome");
        readWords();
        Collections.shuffle(words);
        words.forEach(word -> {
            if (CheckValidity.checkValidity(word)) {
                System.out.println(word);
                try(PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt",true)))
                {
                    writer.printf("%s\r\n", word);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
```

How would I implement this in multithreading? I couldn't find any information that made sense to me where I could input a value into a method any free thread. Sorry if this isn't quite how multithreading works, i've never written anything with more than one thread before so I don't know what's possible and whats not.

Comment: In this case, the bottleneck can easily be the IO oeprations (writing to the output file). You (probably) won't gain much from multithreading here.

Comment: That said, it sounds like you are trying to reinvent [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). The JavaDocs of that class (and the ones referenced from there) are a good starting point.

Comment: Or perhaps parallel Streams are a more suitable abstraction for you - see [the package description of `java.util.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).

Comment: ok, I will check that out. The bottleneck definitely isn't the IO operations, whats consuming the most time is I'm checking the words with an API, so the time it takes for the website to respond is the bottleneck.

Comment: Either way, it is almost certainly faster to collect the valid words in memory first, and only write to the file once you are done.

Comment: Ah ok - if `CheckValidity.checkValidity(word)` actually calls a remote service, calling it asynchronously may indeed help.

Comment: What @Hulk said!  "Assigning tasks to existing threads" is what _[thread pools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool)_ do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way to parallelize your calls to `CheckValidity` would be to use a parallel Stream. Something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> words = readWords();
        Collections.shuffle(words);

        words.stream()
            .unordered()
            .parallel()
            .filter(CheckValidity::checkValidity)
            .forEach(word -> {
                System.out.println(word);
                try(PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt",true)))
                {
                    writer.printf("%s\r\n", word);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
            });
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
```

However, this should not be your production solution if your application also does other things in parallel, as this internally uses the common [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html), and blocking that with non-CPU bound operations may slow down other parts of your application (for example other parallel streams).

For a more robust solution, you should have a look at [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), which allows to create separate thread pools with defined sizes, timeouts etc.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use the parallel stream you gave me and [this](https://www.codementor.io/@nitinpuri/controlling-parallelism-of-java-8-collection-streams-umex0qbt1) article in order to make my program run about 10 timer faster.